# Is it safe to store user password with AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native, security

I want to build an app with auto-login functionality. For that, I want to store username and password at the client with AsyncStorage.

Is it safe? Or is there a better way to implement auto login?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short? No.

You would want to make sure your API (if you're using one of course) returns some form of user code, which you then want to save. If you want to handle everything locally, I would propose to at least encrypt the password (using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bcrypt) and check the password that is filled in with your hashed password that you store using AsyncStorage.

By storing the user token, you can still quite easily 'auto-login' by simply checking if a value for this user token exists.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you explain why it is not secure? After all the browser also stores  passwords and other sensitive data locally...!
I think that storing a token is not the better approach because the token expires after a while so the user will have to enter his credentials again.. (am I wrong?) thanks.

Comment: On why it is not secure:
The way you implement AsyncStorage is by defining a certain key, which then internally gets converted to an address where this value is stored. In theory it could be possible for other applications to also access this value, so that is not secure.
On the token expiration:
Usually tokens are coupled by having an authorization token and a refresh token. Your refresh token makes sure to refresh your authorization token whenever it expires. When your refresh token expires, then yes, you will have to log in again, but that is only for the better